# How to ssh into a VM via mobile devices like phone/tablet?

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I’m new to Linux.
I have a server/vps that disable password log-in and only allow to work with RSA public key.

I just download an iPad app, and trying to connect to my VM, I can’t.
It's make sense because I disable the password.

My RSA public key is stored inside my `.ssh/` folder in my Mac.

---

## Question

Should I move copy the public key from my Mac and use the same one ?
Should I find a way to create a new key on my iPad ?

I used [Coda](https://panic.com/coda-ios/) for iPad.

I’m opening to any hints / tips / suggestions regarding this.

Comment: This is not a question about Ubuntu. It's a software search for your mobile devices so this isn't the right place to ask. The change you'll get an answer here is very slim.

Comment: My VM is Ubuntu, and it's linux related, so I thought it would fit here.

Comment: You would need the private key, not the public key, on the device you are connecting from. In that instance, you'd install the private key on your phone to connect from your phone to your server. Sadly, though, this falls into a different problem. Realistically you need support using whatever app you're using as an SSH client.

Comment: I used [Coda](https://panic.com/coda-ios/) for iPad.

Comment: Which VM software are you using? Are you using a NAT configuration for the VM network adapter? Try using a Bridge configuration as the VM will get an IP directly from your router. Also, how many RSA keys did you generate? Are all of them configured to allow logging in to ssh on the VM. I ussualy just have one RSA key and copy it among my devices.

Comment: My web server runs on Ubuntu, but asking which web browser I should use on Windows to connect to it isn't on topic here. Just because there's Linux somewhere in there doesn't mean the question is actually about Linux. Since your question is not asking how to set the server up (you already have that working), there's no relation to Ubuntu. It could be a Mac or Windows server and the question would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh) if you happen to use an Android phone. It's by far the best SSH client for Android I have seen and supports login via password as well as login via private key authorization.

Using different SSH keys for different devices has the disadvantage that you have to handle different keys but the advantage that should one of the devices get compromised, you can just delete that one corresponding pubic key from the server and don't have to hustle to create a new private key on a different device asap and switch the public keys out. So I'd recommend to use different keys for different devices but that's of course personal choice.

You might not be able to create SSH keys inside an app. In this case, create more keys on your computer and transfer them to your mobile devices. To create them, simply run:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "yourEmailAddress@host.com"
```

To make your server accept connections using different private keys, append the file `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server with the public key. The default location for the public key of your first key pair is `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks for your tips about multi devices with multi keys. You mentioned transfer them to my devices ? you mean copy the actual file OR copy the strings inside the file, and then maybe email it to myself or something right ?

Comment: Apps usually let you choose a file containing the private key or the private key encrypted with your passphrase.  But of course it's also possible that the app developer chose to let users paste the private key as text. It depends on the app and I don't know which one you're going to choose. JuiceSSH will let you do either. Choose which one you like more.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

1. Is your VM's IP discoverable  from ipad? ( I mean you need to give
   bridged network for your vm to give access to local network).
2. Do you have private key string with you?

Then ,

Install iTerminal app in your iPad then add your private key in key management menu , then connect to your VM

Or else you can use any private key authentication supported ssh client app. :)

Comment: So I can just copy my private key and paste, right ?

Comment: yes , thats it.